# Deep Learning Model not generalizing

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a siamese model to differentiate between two handwritten words. Model takes two images containing handwritten word as an input and returns the similarity score between the images. I am treating this problem as pattern matching problem.

To train the model I have prepared a dataset of for 50 handwritten words. Dataset looks something like this:

- For every word I have made positive and negative samples.

  - Positive samples contain word correctly written. For each word I have  around 40 positive samples.
  - Similarly negative samples contain word written incorrectly. For each word I have  around 40 negative samples.
- Then I have augmented the data with rotation, random zoom and shift. I have generated 3 augmented images for each sample.
- In total I have around 13,000 images(positive + negative) containing handwritten words.
- To train the siamese model I have prepared pairs of (positive, positive) and (positive, negative) samples out of my 13,000 images. The distance between (positive, positive) pair is has been kept `0` for training and similarly for (positive, negative) pairs it is `1` .The ratio of the total number of both pair types is 1. So, after pairing I have 900,000+ training pairs. Example of training pairs:

[image]

**Training:**

- The model was trained for 9 epochs before the training was stopped by early stopping callback.
- While training I have saved the model after every epoch. Then, I calculated the optimum accuracy of every model(model saved after each epoch) for the thresholds ranging between the 0-4, on the training and validation sets. These are the results:

> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-001.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9148792424521732     Val_Acc: 0.9155029059218598     Train_thresh:0.46     Val_thresh: 0.45
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-002.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9611607731639384     Val_Acc: 0.9553975714544457     Train_thresh:0.9     Val_thresh: 0.88
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-003.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9917850274632911     Val_Acc: 0.9910994343036379     Train_thresh:0.821     Val_thresh: 0.86
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-004.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9733841038804691     Val_Acc: 0.9751037440663962     Train_thresh:0.08     Val_thresh: 0.08
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-005.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9688207744827331     Val_Acc: 0.966909018821772     Train_thresh:0.05     Val_thresh: 0.05
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-006.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9751844029504473     Val_Acc: 0.9773983855349668     Train_thresh:1.6     Val_thresh: 1.56
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-007.h5     Train_Acc: 0.573793840947319     Val_Acc: 0.5815152521697614     Train_thresh:0.01     Val_thresh: 0.01
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-008.h5     Train_Acc: 0.7119624704175049     Val_Acc: 0.7147077374129519     Train_thresh:0.02     Val_thresh: 0.02
>
> Model_Name: signet-bhsig260-009.h5     Train_Acc: 0.9496454966527798     Val_Acc: 0.9441032442260764     Train_thresh:1.6     Val_thresh: 1.56

**Testing:**

- To test the model I wrote a text on paper containing the words from my dataset and some random words. These are the result using models from third and twelfth epoch:

[image]

[image]

- Earlier model is detecting that every word is from database. Later model is not having this problem.
- Both models are classifying every detected word wrong.

I have checked the models on training data and the predictions are pretty good. I have checked my code multiple times. There are no problems in word segmentation and image pre-processing. The words written on above test image are visually very similar to the images present in my training data. Still, my model is not generalizing on unseen data.

Also, while I was training the model, I randomly selected the 10000 images from my training data and used them for validation while training the model. As seen from the above training results, model's performance on validation data is comparable with training data.